# ColdFusion: Can you pull out a unique record from a query using recordCount?

Tags: coldfusion

It's a bit of tricky question, however, my page for most rated bands displays the band logos in order of how high they have been rated. My only problem is i want to count through the records by using a cfloop from 1 to 10 and because it is split in to two columns, have one counting 1 through to 9 and the other 2 through to 10, each of them with steps of two.

Can anybody help me with this? If i've confused just mention it and ill try to clarify exactly what i mean.

```
    <DIV class="community_middle">

    <cfoutput query="top10MostRated">
        <cfloop from="2" to="10" index="i" step="2">
        <DIV class="communityContent">
                            #chr(i)#
            <IMG src="logo/#top10MostRated.Logo#" alt="#top10MostRated.Name#" width="100%" height="100%"></IMG>
        </DIV>
        <BR/>
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>

</DIV>
```

Comment: Do you mean to display a column of odd and another of even numbers?

Comment: Yes, hit it bang on. I've managed to display them fine, the way im doing it is creating five <DIV>'s on each side from using the counter. The problem comes when i include the <IMG> tags within it, as it creates 5 div's using the counter, but each one is of the same logo before creating another 5 divs with the next logo. Ill edit the original post to include my code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do odd/even lists separately, then you can use the currentrow property of the query combined with the modulo operator (%) to work out if the row is odd or even:

```
<cfloop query="topBands>
  <cfif topBands.currentRow % 2 = 1>
    <!--- do your odd number output here --->
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfloop query="topBands>
  <cfif topBands.currentRow % 2 = 0>
    <!--- do your even number output here --->
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: This would work but why loop multiple times (imagine 5 columns or more with > 10 records)?

Comment: I wasn't sure how the output needed to be used (I had two completely separate areas in mind for odd/even) but you're right, these could combined in one loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think these answers address your side-by-side part of your question but does not explain the  "same image" issue. Their code is written correctly but does not explain the reason.

Your code:

```
        <IMG src="logo/#top10MostRated.Logo#" 
             alt="#top10MostRated.Name#" 
             width="100%" height="100%"></IMG>
```

... would be fine if you were only inside a `<cfloop query = "top10MostRated">` or `<cfoutput query = "top10MostRated">` block.  The reason is because inside these types of blocks CF is smart enough to know you want the data for the current row.  It would be the same as:

```
        <IMG src="logo/#top10MostRated.Logo[top10MostRated.currentRow]#" 
             alt="#top10MostRated.Name[top10MostRated.currentRow]#" 
             width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Because you're nesting the to/from `cfloop` inside a `<cfoutput query = "">` block, you are getting unexpected results. Your existing code is always asking for the record provided by your outer loop. Hence you see the same image 5 times.  (using any of the fine examples provided will help you get out of this) but, you can remove the query from your `cfoutput` and simply ask CF to show you the value for the correct row in your loop using your index (you set your index to "i") so the below would show you the image that corresponds to your loop.

```
        <IMG src="logo/#top10MostRated.Logo[i]#" 
              alt="#top10MostRated.Name[i]#" 
              width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Comment: My new life goal is to write a SO answer that meets Leigh's standards. <3

Comment: Haha, good luck with that. I often edit my own answers .. multiple times ;-) (Constantly searching for improvements)

Answer (score 0):

Ben Nadel has a post exactly for this. Link [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/665-And-On-The-Seventh-Row-MOD-Created-1-And-It-Was-Good.htm)
A breakdown for this is

```
<cfloop query="top10MostRated">
    <cfif top10MostRated.CurrentRow MOD 2>
        <!--- Add to the "odd list" --->
    <cfelse>
        <!--- Add the record to the "even list" --->
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Then you'll have 2 lists *oddList* and *evenList*. Then it's just a matter of displaying them.

Comment: Links are good, but often break over time. Best to include a summary of the key details here as well. So the information is still available here if the link goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it a different way.  The objective is to have records 1 and 2 side by side and I don't see that in @barnyr's answer.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="2" to="topbands.recordcount + 1" index = "i" step="2">
    #topbands.fieldname[i-1]#  
    <cfif i lte topbands.recordcount>
        #topbands.fieldname[i]# <br />
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you'd like to get is a collection of even-numbered records and a collection of odd-numbered records. In Coldfusion 10 or Railo 4, you can use [groupBy()](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/#groupBy) from Underscore.cfc to split up your query result into manageable sub-sets, like so:

```
_ = new Underscore();// instantiate the library
groupedBands = _.groupBy(topBands, function (val, index) {
   return index % 2 ? "odd" : "even";
});
```

This returns a struct with two elements `odd` and `even`, each containing an array of records which are odd or even. Example result:

```
{
   odd: [{name: "Band one"}, {name: "Band three"}],
   even: [{name: "Band two"}, {name: "Band four"}]
}
```

Splitting your results into logical sub-sets makes the code more readable:

```
<cfoutput>
   <cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i">
      <div class="left">#groupedBands.odd[i].name#</div>
      <div class="right">#groupedBands.even[i].name#</div>
   </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

You'll also be able to use those sub-sets in other places on your page if you need to.

Note: I wrote Underscore.cfc