# Nested <cfloop> to display query results - <UL> or table?

Tags: algorithm, coldfusion

I'm trying to output a query set in chunks, in a wide horizontal band.  I.e., given a resultset of 46 items grouped by 4 -

```
div1<br>1 2<br>3 4
<br>
div2<br>5 6<br>7 8
<br>
........
<br> 
div12<br>45 46
```

How can I properly nest a couple of <CFLOOP> to properly output this, and would it be cleaner to do so as a table?  The ultimate goal is to be able to jump(scroll) to each div as an anchor.

I'm having trouble coming up with a solution using either a table or an <UL>.  Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: are those div1 to div12 actual `<div>` or just the text `div` you need to output?

Comment: This sounds very similar to this question.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839586/coldfusion-can-you-pull-out-a-unique-record-from-a-query-using-recordcount

Answer (score 1):

Try Peter suggestion first, if that doesn't work, this algorithm should work.

```
<cfloop query="q">
  <cfif (q.currentRow-1) % 4 EQ 0>
      <br>div#q.currentRow\4+1#
  </cfif>
  <cfif q.currentRow % 2 EQ 1>
    <br>
  </cfif>
  #q.currentRow#
</cfloop>
```

You should check for edge cases yourself.

Comment: I was misunderstanding what the OP was asking - I think this answer will provide it, but probably want to change the `<br/>` in the first cfif to `<div id="div#q.currentRow\4+1#">`

Comment: @PeterBoughton I'm not sure if that's what the OP wants either. :)

Comment: Also, probably worth explaining that `\\` does integer division - not everyone knows that.

Comment: @PeterBoughton provided that he is not asking a homework question, I assume he is capable of looking it up himself if he indeed doesn't know what's integer division. :)

Comment: @Henry, what difference does it make whether or not it's homework?