# Creating An Ascii Check and Count

Tags: coldfusion, ascii

Basically i've created a search page on my website and I need to display each band name/track/location A-Z. I've successfully listed every band in alphabetical order, however i want one half of the page to have 0-9, A-L on it and the other to have M-Z. Is there a way of using Ascii checks + count to check the first letter of each band and call them to the correct alphabet group? Thanks.

Comment: How about starting by showing us how you ended up solving this problem?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839586/coldfusion-can-you-pull-out-a-unique-record-from-a-query-using-recordcount  Then, please verify that you want 23 items on one half and 13 on the other.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to split up a query into sets based on the first letter of a string. In CF 10 or Railo 4, you could use [Underscore.cfc's](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/) [groupBy function](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/#groupBy) to accomplish this like so:

```
_ = new Underscore();

bands_by_name = _.groupBy(bands, function(band) {
   var first_letter = left(band.name, 1);

   if (isNumeric(first_letter))
      return '0-9';
   else if (first_letter <= 'L')
      return 'A-L';
   else
      return 'M-Z';
});
```

`groupBy(collection, callback)` iterates through a collection, applying the callback function to each item and using the return value to group the collection items into a new struct.

In this case, the `bands_by_name` struct would have the keys `0-9`, `A-L`, and `M-Z`, each containing an array of structs containing the relevant results. Example:

```
{
   '0-9': [{name: '1 Band', track: 5, location: 'CA'}, {name: '2Cool', track: 1, location: 'NM'}],
   'A-L': [{name: 'Good Band', track: 2, location: 'NY'}],
   'M-Z': [{name: 'Some Band', track: 3, location: 'PA'}, {name: 'What a Band', track: 2, location: 'NV'}]
}
```

Note: I wrote the Underscore.cfc library.

Comment: Is this supported by CF10 only?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little verbose but it allows for a quick change of columns by adding/changing ascii values to the list `bandGroups`.  **It assumes each column will have data.**

```
<!--- syntax may very depending on database --->
<cfquery ...>
  Select
      bandName
    , trackName
    , location
    , upper(left(bandName,1)) as firstLetter
  from
    someTable
  order by
    bandName
</cfquery>
<!--- 
  create a list of ascii values used to break up your columns
  this will allow you to easily change the number of columns
  End first group at L , end next group at [ (first char after "Z") 
--->
<cfset bandGroups = asc("M") & ',' & asc("[")>
<cfset thisGroup = 1>
<cfset header = '<div style = "float: left; width: #int(100/listLen(bandGroups))#%"><table>'>
<cfoutput>#header#</cfoutput>
    <cfoutput query = "query" group = "firstLetter">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
              #query.firstLetter# 
            </td>
        </tr>
    <cfoutput>
        <tr>
          <td>#query.bandName#</td>
          <td>#query.trackName#</td>
          <td>#query.location#</td>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>
    <cfif query.recordCount eq query.currentRow or asc(query.firstLetter) gte listGetAt(bandGroups, thisGroup)>
        <cfset thisGroup++>
        </table>
        </div>
        <cfif query.currentRow neq query.recordCount>
            #header#
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```